# Session-Timeout with Annotation Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, session-timeout

I have Java based configuration spring 4 and my webAppIntializer implements WebApplicationInitializer and I wanted to implement Session timeout without using web.xml I have the following class in place

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("==== Session is created ====");
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(5*60);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("==== Session is destroyed ====");
    }
}
```

and on my WebAppIntializer I have but the `super.onStartup` is giving me error because it is not found under `WebApplicationInitializer` but rather `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` I dont want to make a code change. Is there a work around Where I can get the session time out to work for me.

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext); // this line is giving me error
    servletContext.addListener(new SessionListener());
}
```

HELP!!!

Comment: Just don't call `super.onStartup`...

Comment: Forgot to add a Listener on web.xml                                                 <listener>
  <listener-class></listener-class>
</listener>